# PHP header("Location: $path") works on Chrome/Firefox but doesn't work on Safari

Tags: php, redirect, safari, header

As Title says, The PHP code is perfectly fine in Chrome/Firefox but gives an error in Safari. I also checked the cache problem on safari so it is not because of that but I am still open to suggestions about the cache problem. However, I do not think it is likely to because of the cache problem. I couldn't find a generally accepted answer for this problem online and most of the answers I found didn't work. Anyways, I am using the following code for opening a pdf with PHP using redirection. I get pdf paths from a table and they are correct.

```
    <?PHP 
    $mish = $_GET['mission'];
    $dbLink = new mysqli('server','user name','password','database name');
      if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
      }
    $queryTotal = "SELECT pdf_path FROM table WHERE id = '$mish' ";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbLink, $queryTotal);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        header("Location: ".$row['pdf_path']); **// I believe this line is problematic**
        exit();
      }
    ?>
```

I checked the $row['pdf_path'] paths and they are correct, they are working on Chrome anyways. When I comment out header line code flows instead of giving an error but of course, opens a blank page.

***Safari Can't Open the Page***

***Safari can't open the page "server_name/php_pdf_reader_with_correct_mission" because the page's address isn't valid.***

This is the error I get. I replace the name of the server etc. but the general picture is there. I also tried the first answers I get when I searched the problem online, like adding the javascript redirection line as follows. It didn't work too. But I am not familiar with js I may have a typo or something.

```
echo '<script>window.location = "'.$row['pdf_path'].'";</script>';
die;
```

I also tried to add **ob_start();** over and there but it didn't change anything.

EDIT:

```
header('Location: http:' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]. rawurldecode($path));
```

I tried this code and it redirects and works for safari. HOWEVER, now it is not working on Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So Safari is able to open that URL _directly_ then, if you do not try to redirect to it, but enter it via the address bar? Are you using an absolute or a relative URL in your Location header?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Thanks, @ADyson it is one of my school's server and I am not responsible for the security issues and this is how they told me to do. Thanks for the warning though, I will consider it when I will deal with my own projects.

Comment: Hi, @CBroe, When I directly copy and paste the path in $row['pdf_path'] it works in Safarş too. So, pdfs are there and the path is correct, also, the path is working if I would copy and paste the path in safari.

Comment: Still not clear whether you are using an absolute or a relative URL in the location header.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I am using the absolute URLs. I was not aware of that distinction. I checked online and as far as I understand, URLs in the $path are absolute URLs. I have http:\\ staff at the beginning.

Comment: `I am not responsible for the security issues`....maybe not overall, but in the code you write yourself, you're responsible for basic security within it. I'm sure they didn't specifically tell you to write insecure code. If they did, then they need to update their knowledge! It's best to learn it the right way now - it isn't difficult, and then if you do more programming in future you won't have to re-learn the techniques. It also helps to prevent certain other issues as well, e.g. the query could break if the entered data contains an apostrophe or anything like that.

Comment: @ADyson, I believe you are right. I need to be more careful. I check that stuff and will try to solve it. Thnx for stating the importance of the subject again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and wanted to share it from here.

```
$path = $row['pdf_path'];
$browser = get_browser();
if($browser[browser] == 'Safari') {
    header('Location: http:' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]. rawurldecode($path));
}
else {
    header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header( "Location: $path" );
    echo '<script>window.location = "'.$path.'";</script>';
    echo 'window.location.replace('.$path.');';
    die;
}
```

It is not as elegant as I hoping for but It works. I still do not know what is the problem but this worked out for me!

Answer (score -2):

Try this code, because it contains HTTP response code

```
<?php
 $url_path = 'public path to file';
 header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
 header( "Location: $url_path" );
 // Backup code
 echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url_path.'";</script>';
 echo 'window.location.replace('+$url_path+');';
 die;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, it does not work in Chrome, I am receiving HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: Hi @bidon there were special characters in the code thats why it gave you 500 error. please check again, i have edited the code.

Comment: Yes, I checked again and it works for Chrome now as it before. However, It still gives the same error in safari...

Comment: @bidon can you paste one of the redirect url.

Comment: do not want to copy-paste the direct link but it something like this. http://servername/folder/file.pdf. Sorry for this mysterious attitude but someone state that there is a security problem in my code and just wanted to be careful.

Comment: $url_path should also have full path to the file including the domain name followed by file path dfor example, $url_path ='http://example.com/path/to/your/pdf_file.pdf';